# external hard drive not recognized

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

i recently bought a 500GB iomega eGo external hard drive. It use to work fine but now when i plug it into my USB the drive doesn't show up in my computer or disk manager. But when in device manages it shows that the hard drive has been detected. When i try to populate some times it shows as "in accessible" and some times "unreadable".

Can someone please suggest me whats wrong and what am i supposed to do to make my drive show in my computer?

Comment: Does it show up into the BIOS first?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you plug it into another computer, or is the problem isolated only to the one computer?

If it doesn't work with another computer either, I would guess that the drive went bad. You may be able to have it replaced under warranty, if you recently bought it.

If it does work on another computer, I would guess that something is not working correctly with your USB sub-system.